# How to separate a development environment from a production environment

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn, aptana

I have just installed Aptana studio 2, and it looks really nice. I would like to separate my work into editing the local development server, and editing the production server. That way I don't end up accidentally editting the production server with development changes. I believe that in order to do this I would need the mylyn *Focus on active task* filter in the Aptana file view, and I'm wondering how I can do that. Or is there another way I can achieve the same thing?

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup a different workspace for different projects.  It each workspace will save the open windows and different views along with your settings.

You can create a new workspace by going to File -> Switch Workspace -> Other...

Comment: Cool, would it be possible to have both workspaces open at once, for copying back and forth?

Comment: That depends on what you use to connect to your servers.  You can access all of your server connections under the FTP item in the File view if you want to use the native connections Aptana provides, but will have to add them to each workspace you want access to them in.